# how to run jquery in ajax response page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using an AJAX pagination and that is working fine.

It returns the data succesfully. e.g:-

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{ 
document.getElementById("NewsFeedListID").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Now NewsFeedListID div contains the correct data.

Now I have to use jQuery on that response AJAX page, but jQuery is not working.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you go into some more detail about what jQuery code isn't working?

Comment: How is it not working? How are you including it? Note that you'll need to include jQuery in **your** page. There's no reason you can't use jQuery on the DOM elements created by your assignment to `innerHTML` above.

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery not working? Is the global object ($) failing to execute functions. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Let me expalin.  in ajax response page. i.e                      <div id="NewsFeedListID">                                          <a id="delete" href="#">Delete</a></div> and i am including jquery on that page as <script language="JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
         $('#delete').click(function() {
           alert("success");

       });

 });

</script>                                                       when i click on delete it should alert success but its not working why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your explanation in the comments section of your question I believe [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589264/josh) has hit upon the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900460/how-to-run-jquery-in-ajax-response-page/4901322#4901322).

The reason your jQuery event is not working is because, you "attach" the event handlers using `$('#delete').click(function() {alert('success');})` to the anchor/button with id "delete" (that's the #delete part), then later that anchor "#delete" get's removed from the DOM when you replace the innerHTML of "#NewsFeedListID", so you would either have to re-attach the event handlers to #delete, or as [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589264/josh) has suggested use a technique known as event delegation to keep the click event triggering even though you are replacing the innerHTML.

I'll leave it to you to look into "event delegation" and using jQuery to simplify your ajax requests (look into the method "[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)" for a very simple alternative to what you are describing) but use `$('#delete').live('click',function() {alert('success');})` to solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to include jQuery in the original page, not the AJAX request, then use `.live()` to bind the event.  This will bind the event to the element whether or not it is included on the page. Then when you insert the element via AJAX, your button will work.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you are having the JS code in the returned page, which doesnt work, and It wont work because setting the innerHTML doesnt execute the JS in it, it just places HTML code there, to execute the JS code here you will have to **eval** the code after you insert it in the page.

Eval is never a good idea, I would suggest you to have all your JS code in original page, and use .live() function of jquery to attach events to elements that arent present on your page when its loaded.

Comment: And Naveed you dont have to include the script for jquery again in your ajax response for the new page, you already have jQuery loaded on the page.

Comment: EDIT - 
And Naveen you dont have to include the script for jquery in your ajax response for the new page, you shounld include it on your main page